# How can I write $\frac{(4k-15)\pi}8$ as $n+2k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $n\in(-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I write $\frac{(4k-15)\pi}8$ as $n+2k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $n\in(-\pi,\pi]$

$\boxed{\bf My\,try::}$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(4k-15)\pi}{8}&=\frac{4k\pi-15\pi}{8}\\ &=\frac{4k\pi-16\pi+\pi}{8}\\ &=\frac{4(k\pi-4\pi)+\pi}{8}\\&=\frac{k\pi-4\pi}2+\pi/8
\end{align}$$

then I can't.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem) of $4k-15$ by $8$.

Comment: @metacompactness I don't know about it, could you clarify a bit please?

Comment: For example, if you want write $\frac{51}{5}\pi$ in the form $n+2k\pi$, you'll divide $51$ by $5$, you'll get $quotient=10$ and $remainder=1$ so that $51=5\times 10+1$. $$\frac{51}{5}\pi=\frac{5\times 10+1}{5}\pi=\frac{\pi}{5}+2\times 5\times \pi$$

Comment: @metacompactness 4k-15 by 8 is: $\frac{1/2\times 8 + 0}8 \pi=?$ euh

Comment: I added an answer that doesn't use Euclidean division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ is even then we can write $k=2\ell$ with $\ell\in\Bbb{Z}$.

$$\frac{4k-15}{8}\pi=\frac{8\ell-15}{8}\pi=(\ell-2)\pi+\frac{\pi}{8}$$

If $k$ is odd then we can write $k=2\ell+1$ with $\ell\in\Bbb{Z}$.

$$\frac{4k-15}{8}\pi=\frac{8\ell-11}{8}\pi=(\ell-2)\pi+\frac{5}{8}\pi$$

Comment: Thank you so much maaaaan!! That's really really helpful!

Comment: but I think you made an error, it's not $\frac58\pi$

Comment: ah no I apologize you are right